# Parameterising `LIMIT ALL` in pg-promise

Tags: pg-promise

I have this simple query:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ${pageSortKey:name} ${pageSortDir:raw} LIMIT ${pageLimit} OFFSET ${pageOffset}`

How do I pass `ALL` for `LIMIT` ?

As far as I understand it - `${pageLimit}` is treated as an int and thus if I try to pass the argument `'ALL'` to it, I got:

"invalid input syntax for type bigint: \"ALL\""

Much appreciated for reading.

Comment: `As far as I understand it - ${pageLimit} is treated as an int` - What do you mean by that? It takes whatever you pass in. You can either change it to `${pageLimit:raw}`, and then you can pass in `ALL` also, or you can create a custom type via [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is to make it use the value directly, by changing the variable to `${pageLimit:raw}`.

A safer approach is to create your own custom type for it, using [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```js
const limit = val => ({rawType: true, toPostgres: () => val ?? 'ALL'});
```

Then pass the function result as the value into the query, which will produce:

- `limit(0)` => `0`
- `limit(123)` => `123`
- `limit()` => `ALL`
- `limit(null)` => `ALL`

The second approach is better, but usually, you would choose to wrap the entire `LIMIT` logic into it, and not just the limit value:

```js
const limit = val => ({ rawType: true, toPostgres: () => val ? `LIMIT ${val}` : '' });
```

To produce the entire `LIMIT` clause only when there is an actual limit to be applied:

- `limit(0)` => ``
- `limit()` => ``
- `limit(null)` => ``
- `limit(123)` => `LIMIT 123`

**examples:**

```js
db.any('SELECT * FROM table $1', [limit(123)]);
//=> SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 123

db.any('SELECT * FROM table ${limit}', {limit: limit(123)});
//=> SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 123
```

Comment: hello - appreciate your answer and i think Custom Type Formatting is what I'm looking for and btw - i had been enjoying using your library: it's really useful.